# My code doesn't return the expected value (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get volumes that are in a sheet called volumes, and in this sheet I have many volumes from 2019 to 2026, and this for many projects in rows.

I want to get the volume by comparing each cell in Column C of the sheet `Loaded_Plan` to each row in column C in the sheet `Volumes`. I've tried to make a column Y in `Loaded_Plan` sheet for this but it doesn't work. Below is the code :

```
Dim rngProject Set rngProject = wsVolumes.Range(wsVolumes.Cells(5, "B"), wsVolumes.Cells(wsVolumes.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) 'Dim rngVolume Set rngVolume = wsVolumes.Range(wsVolumes.Cells(5, "B"), wsVolumes.Cells(wsVolumes.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rngProject

    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value = Application.VLookup(cell, wsLoaded_Plan.Range("C:C"), 1, False)
    ' Ne copie colle que cette ligne d'après
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 8).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 4, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 10).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 5, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 12).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 6, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 14).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 7, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 16).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 8, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 20).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 9, False)
    wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 22).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 10, False)
 Next cell

Dim rngProject
    Set rngProject = wsVolumes.Range(wsVolumes.Cells(5, "B"), wsVolumes.Cells(wsVolumes.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Dim rngVolume
    Set rngVolume = wsVolumes.Range(wsVolumes.Cells(5, "B"), wsVolumes.Cells(wsVolumes.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In rngProject

        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value = Application.VLookup(cell, wsLoaded_Plan.Range("C:C"), 1, False)
        ' Ne copie colle que cette ligne d'après
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 8).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 4, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 10).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 5, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 12).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 6, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 14).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 7, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 16).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 8, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 20).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 9, False)
        wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 22).Value = Application.VLookup(wsLoaded_Plan.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 23).Value, rngVolume, 10, False)
     Next cell

 End

End Sub
```

I am expecting to get the volumes from sheet `Volumes` from columns : F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M, to the sheet `Loaded_Plan` in columns I,K,M,O,Q,S,U,W, with respect to the project in rows. What I want is two volumes: one for 2019 and the other for 2020 (but it is not done in the suitable row, the matching between projects is not correct).

[Excel document](https://audencia0-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/yasmine_idrissi_audencia_com/EZrWrJXHtWZNhDVQl1rd04IBs6BwU_1M778P1dtUE-wFpQ?e=G9qg1q).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it will helpful if you could post a data example (the input you got and the expected output)

Comment: Rather share a file that reproduces the problem, but has sensitive information removed.  Or post a sample of Text that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet to do the same thing. A screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting unless it is very brief. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)